# use "this" to access DOM element attributes and JS constructor's methods in an event handler

Tags: javascript, events, constructor, this

I am trying to use the methods from a javascript constructor as event handlers, and also access the id attribute of the DOM element that the handler is bound to.
I know that once the event listener and associated callback function have been attached to a DOM element the value of "this" inside the callback function will point to that DOM element and not the constructor where the function was defined. So, how can I call the methods defined in my js constructor from an event handler?
Currently when I click an element I get the error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOpponent' of undefined

This is the the code that is not working, and [here](https://codepen.io/hazardsteven/pen/ZoXebX?editors=0011) is a link to my full project on codepen.

```
function DOM(){
    /*store references to DOM elements*/
}

function Board(){
    /*props and methods to keep track of open/occupied squares*/
}

 function Game(){
    this.dom = new DOM();
    this.board = new Board();

    /*props and methods for the game*/

    this.attachEventHandlers = function(){
        $(this.dom.$opponentOption).on("click", function(){
                var opponent = $(this).attr("id");
                this.setOpponent(opponent).bind(this);
            });

            $(this.dom.$characterOption).on("click", function(){
                var character = $(this).attr("id");
                this.setCharacter(character).bind(this);
            });

            $(this.dom.$square).on("click", function(){
                var square = $(this).attr("id");
                this.squareClickHandler(square).bind(this);
            })

            $(this.dom.$reset).on("click", function(){
                this.resetGame().bind(this);
            });
  };
}
var game = new Game();
game.attachEventHandlers();
```

Comment: simply store reference to `this` just inside `attachEventHandlers ` and use that reference inside the actual event handlers

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and the selected answer in that question are exactly what I was looking for.